# What did i do wrong in bind settings?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bind

I have a machine on my network that I am using as a DNS server / file server and it is running webmin. its ip is 192.168.0.223 and when i try to connect to it without ssl on the webmin port (http://192.168.0.223:10000) i get the webmin notification page as usual saying to use ssl to connect to it. however, the link it is giving me is wrong and has the reverse record in it as the domain name: "This web server is running in SSL mode. Try the URL https://example.com.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa:10000/ instead."

Im guessing this is due to me setting up something incorrectly in bind. What do I need to change so this link has the correct hostname or ip?

```
office.com.   IN  SOA     ns.office.com.    admin.office.com.(
2006081401
28800
3600
604800
38400

)

office.com.   IN  NS      ns.office.com.
office.com.   IN  MX  10  mail.office.com.

scholes             IN  A   192.168.0.220
noc                 IN  A   192.168.0.220
ns                  IN  A   192.168.0.223
mail                IN  A   192.168.0.223
```

and the reverse record is

```
@   IN  SOA ns.office.com. admin.office.com.(

    2006081401;
    28800;
    604800;
    604800;
    86400
)

        IN      NS      ns.office.com.
223     IN      PTR     office.com.
```

@Mike - added reverse and normal zone file source

Comment: @David Schwartz  added normal and reverse zone files to original post

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `.` at the end of `example.com` in the zone `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa`.

Comment: I thought so too, but this is my reverse zone: 
`@   IN  SOA ns.office.com. admin.office.com.(

    2006081401;
    28800;
    604800;
    604800;
    86400
)

        IN      NS      ns.office.com.
223     IN      PTR     office.com.
`

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you missed a trailing . after a full hostname in bind.. but it's hard to tell without seeing logs and the zone file in question

like a PTR would be like

```
 3 IN PTR hostname.domain.com.
```

Comment: I thought this was the case also, but I am not missing the trailing period.`@ IN SOA ns.office.com. admin.office.com.( 
2006081401; 
28800; 
604800; 
604800; 
86400 ) 
     IN NS ns.office.com. 
223 IN PTR office.com.`